# rails 4 scopes with NOT equal and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, scopes

I have a instance variable in my controller that I'm trying to convert into a scope for my model.

Instance variable: products

```
@products_with_user_differences = Product.where{|p| p.last_user != p.user.username && p.asset_type.name == "Computer" unless p.user.nil? or p.allow_multi_users == true}
```

Explanation:

This shows all Products that have a **last_user** value different from the **user.username** with a type of **"Computer"**. It also excludes any Product that **user_id:** is **nil** or have **allow_multi_users** attribute set to **TRUE**.

I've tried the following with zero luck: Products.rb

```
scope :with_user_differences, -> { where(last_user != user.username && asset_type.name == "Computer" unless user.nil? or allow_multi_users == true)}
```

It doesn't seem to recognize associations or allow "!=" in the scope.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: In the first version you're using `where{` and in the second version `where(`. [A normal ActiveRecord `where`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) definitely can't do what you're trying to do in your scope.

Comment: thanks but i already realize that it can't do that because it doesn't work. any hints on the correct way to do it?

Comment: Sorry if you think my comment wasn't helpful. I thought it'd help you realise *why* it doesn't work. I put a link in there that may be helpful when trying to rewrite your query.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return products that are associated to a `user` and an `asset_type`

```
Product.joins(:user, :asset_type)
```

To exclude products with `allow_multi_users` set to `true`

```
Product.where(allow_multi_users: false)
```

To get products where `asset_type.name` is `computer`, assuming you followed convention and `asset_type` is under a table called `asset_types`

```
# take note of the pluralized asset_type
Product.where(asset_types: { name: 'Computer' })
```

To get products where `last_user` is not equal to the associated user's username

```
Product.where('products.last_user != users.username')
```

Given all these, you can do the following

```
def self.with_user_differences
  Product
    .joins(:user, :asset_type)
    .where(assset_types: { name: 'Computer' })
    .where(allow_multi_users: false)
    .where('products.last_user != users.username')
end
```

Comment: You missed the `asset_type.name == "computer"` condition